# How to get the sasKey or connectionString when developing a module?

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am attempting to write a module where I cannot use the current ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync() and would like to get the module connection string (or SASKey) so I can generate a SAS token and authenticate.

I know that at one time (and in the IoTEdgeDev container) the environment variable EdgeHubConnectionString existed and was later removed.  How can I derive the sasKey in code in a module?  Imaging if I needed/wanted to use Paho in the module instead of the MSFT provided SDK.

**Update**

So I guess I have to sign the URI to create a connection string, similar to manually creating a connection string.

I have tried the code below, but the signature does not match what I get with Azure IoT Explorer.  Any help would be appreciated.  Reference: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/d2c331d605a846911019364a31a7d098e1e2fc45/edgelet/workload/docs/WorkloadApi.md

```
# expecting curl, base64 and jq to be installed
epoch=$(printf '%(%s)T\n' -1)
epoch=$(($epoch+86400))
dataToSign=$IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME"%2Fdevices%2F"$IOTEDGE_DEVICEID"%2Fmodules%2F"$IOTEDGE_MODULEID
signedData=$(echo -n $dataToSign'\n'$epoch | base64 -w 0)
signature=$(curl --unix-socket /var/run/iotedge/workload.sock http://127.0.0.1/modules/$IOTEDGE_MODULEID/genid/$IOTEDGE_MODULEGENERATIONID/sign?api-version=$IOTEDGE_APIVERSION \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"data": "'$signedData'", "keyId": "", "algo": "HMAC-SHA256"}' \
    | jq -r ".digest")

SASToken="SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=$dataToSign&sig=$signature&se=$epoch"
ConnectionString="HostName=$IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME;DeviceId=$IOTEDGE_DEVICEID;ModuleId=$IOTEDGE_MODULEID;$SASToken"
```

Comment: So asking again, as I have hit this issue again.  I see that I can use the command: curl --unix-socket /var/run/iotedge/workload.sock "http://127.0.0.1/modules?api-version=2018-06-28" and get settings about the devices, but I have not see the exposed API of /var/run/iotedge/workload.sock to see how I could get the primary key,  Clearly all the other settings are in the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of iteration, here is how to call the sign API to get a SAS Token:

```
# expecting curl, base64 and jq to be installed in the Linux OS
epoch=$(printf '%(%s)T\n' -1)
epoch=$(($epoch+86400))
WORKLOADURI=$(echo $IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI | sed "s|unix://|""|g")
uri=$(echo $IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME"/devices/"$IOTEDGE_DEVICEID"/modules/"$IOTEDGE_MODULEID | sed "s|/|%2F|g")
signedData=$(echo -n $uri$'\n'$epoch | base64 -w 0)
signature=$(curl --unix-socket $WORKLOADURI http://127.0.0.1/modules/$IOTEDGE_MODULEID/genid/$IOTEDGE_MODULEGENERATIONID/sign?api-version=$IOTEDGE_APIVERSION \
    --request POST --data '{"data": "'$signedData'", "keyId": "", "algo": "HMAC-SHA256"}' \
    | jq -r ".digest" | sed "s|=|%3D|g" | sed "s|+|%2B|g" | sed "s|/|%2F|g")

# here is our SAS Token
SASToken="SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=$uri&sig=$signature&se=$epoch"
# here is a connection string with the SAS Token
ConnectionString="HostName=$IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME;DeviceId=$IOTEDGE_DEVICEID;ModuleId=$IOTEDGE_MODULEID;$SASToken"
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the implementation of `ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync()` in the [C# SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/cf5bb3e1c5bd865ee36345772dfa862b71a21b1a/iothub/device/src/Edge/EdgeModuleClientFactory.cs#L59). It uses the following environment variables to create the connection string:

```
- IOTEDGE_WORKLOADURI          URI for iotedged's workload API
- IOTEDGE_DEVICEID             Device identifier
- IOTEDGE_MODULEID             Module identifier
- IOTEDGE_MODULEGENERATIONID   Module generation identifier
- IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME       IoT Hub host name
- IOTEDGE_AUTHSCHEME           Authentication scheme to use; must be "sasToken"
```

It seems the SAS token is created in the [ModuleAuthenticationWithHsm](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/cf5bb3e1c5bd865ee36345772dfa862b71a21b1a/iothub/device/src/HsmAuthentication/ModuleAuthenticationWithHsm.cs#L13) class, you might be able to base your code on this?